# EditText not scrollable inside the Listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml, android-scrollview

I have `ListView` which is also scrollable and inside it there is MultiLine `EditText` 
which is not scrollable properly when I wanted to scroll the EdiText then Listview's scroll works while I wanted to scroll the Editext. 
so please suggest some good ways to handle this.

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_address"
                style="@style/Text.Medium"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="@string/address"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:maxHeight="75dp"
                android:maxLength="256"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
               />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the line `android:maxHeight="75dp"` and give `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for the edittext. It will automaticcaly wrap its content and there is no necessity to scroll it, to view its content.